# How to display a Rectangle above a Table in Adobe Indesign? (layering)

Tags: vba, adobe-indesign

I have 1 table in InDesign. Now I add a Rectangles on the Page, but it is behind the Table object.
I want the Rectangle to be in front of the table. (i.e. the z-index of the table should be more than the rectangle)

How to achieve this using InDesign scripting?

Comment: Items in the pageitems collection appear in the order of their depths, did you try modifying the index for these items to bring the rectangle up.

Comment: Index of Items readonly. I add Rectangles  from vba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a new layer
2. move to Top layer.
3. move Rectangle to Top layer